# how can i change my spritekit on collision in spritekit swift

Tags: swift

how can i change my spritekit on collision in spritekit swift.

```
        else if collidedBird.birdType == 6 {
            if UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Pad
            {
                _bird.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVectorMake(0, birdImpluseReturn(70.0)))
            } else {
                _bird.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVectorMake(0, birdImpluseReturn(70.0)))
            }
            let fire = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.05, target: self, selector: Selector("createDragonFire"), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
            playEffectSound("BS_Std_Jump_SFX.mp3")
            _platform.removeFromParent()
        }
```

Comment: You might want to provide more details on what you're trying to do.

Comment: My Sprite jump on a platform. I draw the platform by finger touch. Sprite Jump on Platform. On jump platform remove. Again i create platform by finger. Other Sprites move left to right and right to left in game. On specific Sprite collision by my Jumping sprite. I want to change the 
Sprite Image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change the Image of the Sprite, then you should use `SKPhysicsContactDelegate` Method.

In General that means that you have to implement the `SKPhysicsContactDelegate`, Make a new Struct:

For Example:

```
struct PhysicCategories {
        static let NoneC : UInt32 = 0x1 << 0
        static let Bird : UInt32 = 0x1 << 1
        static let PlatformC : UInt32 = 0x1 << 2
        static let FinishC : UInt32 = 0x1 << 3
        static let ObstacleC : UInt32 = 0x1 << 4
    }
```

then go in your `didMoveToView()` function and write:

```
PhysicsWorld.contactdelegate = self
```

> Dont forget to make this Step!

Then add the func

```
func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {

        var contactbody1 = contact.bodyA
        var contactbody2 = contact.bodyB


        if contactbody1.categoryBitMask < contactbody2.categoryBitMask{

            contactbody1 = contact.bodyA
            contactbody2 = contact.bodyB


        } else {

            contactbody1 = contact.bodyB
            contactbody2 = contact.bodyA

        }

        if ((contactbody1.categoryBitMask == PhysicCategories.BirdC) && (contactbody2.categoryBitMask == PhysicCategories.ObstacleC)){
            // Make a GameOver Function for that!
            // GameOver()


        }
        if ((contactbody1.categoryBitMask == PhysicCategories.BirdC) && (contactbody2.categoryBitMask == PhysicCategories.PlatformC)){

            contactbody1.node.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "")



        }
```